# magento prevent or block __store parameter usage

Tags: magento

Our magento site uses one domain per storefront. 
I want to prevent users from switching to another storefront using the query parameter __store.

I'm setting the storecode manually in the index.php at Mage::run depending on the HTTP_HOST which works fine.

Is there a way to prevent the __store parameter from working?

My only idea so far is to filter the parameters within apache and rewrite the request... but i would prefer to use a clean way within magento.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as this param is parsed in [`Mage_Core_Model_App` [link]](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php#L524), it would be less messy to manipulate the request in your web server software.

Additionally, in Apache you should be able to use RewriteCond to set the `MAGE_RUN_CODE` environment variable, which would mean that you can revert your *index.php* file.

What's the goal with this restriction?

Comment: thats what i feared... 
we have no links on our sites to change the storeview because we want the user to browse the one thats specified by the domain... the user must not be able to override what we have set up.

Comment: ...couldn't they just go to one of the other domains?

Comment: yes they can and they should, but at the same time they must not be able to set a different storefront using some obscure parameter.

Comment: You can manipulate the query string at the server level to strip this param, or you can do it in *index.php*.

Comment: we ended up removing it inside magento to get rid of the cause once and for all... this is just one of the many examples of bad programming under magentos hood

Comment: How is this evidence of "bad programming under magentos hood"?

Comment: if theres a hard coded get parameter inside a core class that switches the storefront thats pretty much bad design.

Comment: Is it then evidence of good design that you can unobtrusively modify that behavior by redefining `Mage_Core_Model_App` in the local codepool? Is it not sufficient that you could/should manipulate a *request* parameter before it even hits your app entry point? Magento won't wash your car either.

Comment: Its just bad api-design, in my index.php I initiate mage with a storecode and then later inside its belly magento just overides that if some obscure param is set. The correct way would have been that I set the store code based upon any parameter or mechanism if chose to do so. So if I wanted to use a get param I would have implemented it myself in the index.php

Comment: Since 1.4, *`index.php`* is intended to *not* be modified (you can fashion your own entry point if you wish). As an entry point it is written in part with the assumption that you will manipulate the environment before the app is initialized. Given that you control the environment prior to Magento initializing, you actually *can* control store "based upon any parameter or mechanism if chose to do so". Also, don't conflate general initialization with *user-selected* scope - both a GET param *and* a COOKIE param have something to say about this.